# Speed comparison about if and ?:

Tags: c#, windows

For testing purposes i wrote a simple code. First method is better for coding standards. Second method is traditional way. I am used stopwatch to comparison and i tried everything but couldn't figured out why method 2(traditional) faster than method 1 ? Is (if) faster than ?: operator ?

My form design;
[image: Form Design]

My code;

```
    namespace WindowsFormsApplication3
{
    using System;
    using System.Diagnostics;
    using System.Windows.Forms;

    internal partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private void Button1Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var sw = new Stopwatch();

            sw.Start();

            Method1();

            sw.Stop();

            listBox1.Items.Add($"Method1 -> {sw.Elapsed}");

            sw.Reset();

            sw.Start();

            Method2();

            sw.Stop();

            listBox1.Items.Add($"Method2 -> {sw.Elapsed}");
        }

        private void Method1()
        {
            pictureBox.Visible = !pictureBox.Visible;
            button1.Text = this.button1.Text == "Close" ? "Open" : "Close";
        }

        private void Method2()
        {
            if (pictureBox.Visible)
            {
                pictureBox.Visible = false;
                button1.Text = "Open";
            }
            else
            {
                pictureBox.Visible = true;
                button1.Text = "Close";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Can someone explain to me why Method2(traditional) is better than Method1 ? Thanks.

EDIT:

Changed to this but still Method1 is faster.

```
        private void Method2()
    {
        if (pictureBox.Visible)
        {
            pictureBox.Visible = false;
            if (this.button1.Text == "Close")
            {
                this.button1.Text = "Open";
            }
            else
            {
                this.button1.Text = "Close";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            pictureBox.Visible = true;
            if (this.button1.Text == "Close")
            {
                this.button1.Text = "Open";
            }
            else
            {
                this.button1.Text = "Close";
            }
        }
```

I think it is not about comparison count.

Comment: Your first method has two if statements. Your second method has only one. Is this supposed to be a fair comparison?

Comment: private void Method2()
        {
            if (pictureBox.Visible)
            {
                pictureBox.Visible = false;
                button1.Text = button1.Text == "Close" ? "Open" : "Close";
            }
            else
            {
                pictureBox.Visible = true;
                button1.Text = button1.Text == "Close" ? "Open" : "Close";
            }
        }
If i change to this. Still Method2 is faster.

Comment: Rule of thumb: if you need to ask which is faster, then it doesn't matter. Don't worry about speed until you notice a slowdown.

Comment: I am not trying to do micro optimization. Just trying to understand why ?

Comment: Your test isn't `if` versus the ternary operator, it's different comparison types as explained below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Method1 you are doing a string comparison to check the state of the control.

In Method2 you are doing an boolean comparison.

The latter will be quicker.

Comment: Method2 is a `boolean` comparison

Comment: @DavidPine - Yeah - used to working in WPF/Silverlight where `Visible` is an enum rather than boolean, but the logic still holds.